# How do I make Nivo slider with fixed height responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have an issue which I hope is solvable with CSS rather than modifying the jQuery code itself.

I have a nivo slider with fixed height and responsive width. When you make the window smaller the image shrinks to show 100% of the image width. This is fine and I like that feature, but the smaller the window gets the closer the height of the image gets to not fill out the slider.

I want nivo-slider to act as it is until the height of the image is the same as the sliders height. Then I want the slider to swap from

```
width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

to:

```
height: 100%;
width: auto;
```

Is it possible to force the img to fill the slider with just CSS? Do I need to use "media screen" so once the resolution is small enough I swap using that? That requires me to know the height of the images and at which resolution the problem starts?

Comment: Any chance of seeing the live version?

Comment: Not possible. Still under development :( But if a print screen helps I can provide that. The code is just the default nivo slider with a fixed height set to 220px.